# How to attach css and javascript files in zf2 controller?

Tags: javascript, zend-framework2, stylesheet, zend-controller

i attach some stylesheets in zend controller but blank page shown,how i include stylesheets and javascript files in zend controller?here is my code:

```
public function showAction()
    {       
            //css

            $this->viewHelperManager->get('headLink')->appendStylesheet('/css/style.css');
            $this->viewHelperManager->get('headLink')->appendStylesheet('/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css');
            $this->viewHelperManager->get('headLink')->appendStylesheet('/css/tweaks.css');
            $this->viewHelperManager->get('headLink')->appendStylesheet('/css/fullcalendar.css');
            $this->viewHelperManager->get('headLink')->appendStylesheet('/css/fullcalendar.print.css');
            $this->viewHelperManager->get('headLink')->appendStylesheet('/css/jquery-ui.min.css');
            $this->viewHelperManager->get('headLink')->appendStylesheet('/css/jquery.simple-dtpicker.css');
            //js
            $this->viewHelperManager->get('headScript')->appendFile('/admin_static/js/jquery-ui-1.10.3.custom/js/jquery-ui-1.10.3.custom.min.js');
            $id = (int) $this->params()->fromRoute('id', 0);
            if (!$id) {
                return $this->redirect()->toRoute('calendar', array(
                    'action' => 'create'
                ));
            }
            $calendar = $id;
            $dm = $this->getServiceLocator()->get('doctrine.documentmanager.odm_default');
            $eventshow = $dm->createQueryBuilder('Calendar\Document\Calendar')
            ->hydrate(false)
            ->field("id")->equals($id)
            ->getQuery()->execute();
            $array = array();
            if($eventshow && !is_null($eventshow) && is_object($eventshow)){                    
                foreach($eventshow as $key=>$value) {   
                $array[] = array(
                        'calendar_id' => $value['_id'],
                        'user_id' => $value['user_id'],
                        'title' => $value['title'],
                        'description' => $value['description'], 
                    );
                }
            }
            return array('calendar' => $calendar , 'calendardata' => $array);
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 'blank page' just means an error is being generated but you have `display_errors` turned off. Check your web server error log to see what the actual problem is (this will help you debug future issues as well).

From looking at your code, I'd guess the problem is with the calls to `$this->viewHelperManager`, as there is no such thing (unless you've set that elsewhere in your controller).

You probably want:

```
$this->getServiceLocator()->get('viewhelpermanager')->get('headLink')->appendStylesheet('/css/style.css');
```

although if you need that many view helper calls it might be worth passing the headLink helper in as a dependency.

Comment: $this->getServiceLocator()->get('viewhelpermanager')->get('headScript')->appendFile('/js/jquery.min.js'); according to your code this line not include jquery in zend controller

Comment: Do you have a corresponding `echo $this->headLink()` call in your layout to output the HTML?

Comment: For scripts add $this->headScript();